# Increasing the month by one in a timestamp

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

I am working with timestamps in milliseconds. I want to add one month to a variable each time I go through my `for` loop.

```
for(var i=0;i<record.length;i++)
{
    x += someValue;
}
```

How can I increase my running total by one month each time? Is there a simple value that is equal to the difference between two months? Or do I have to get the timestamps for the two particular months and then subtract the difference?

**EDIT**

I used a modified version of this and it worked in my case.

```
while(year < someYear) 
{
    if(month == 12)
        month = 1;
    else
        month+=1;

    newTimestamp = new Date(year, month, day).getTime()
    x = newTime;
}
```

Comment: How accurate do you need this to be? Exactly one month down to the second? Or just the day? Or nothing but "the next month"?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `month = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; [...] x += month`? (You can simplify it, of course)

Comment: Since months vary in length, your total will be inaccurate unless you're able to specify exactly which month you're going through and adding.

Comment: Convert to time object, increase month by 1 and convert to UNIX.

Comment: @kennebec In this case I didn't care about the day value, so I left it equal to one. However, if I wanted to look at each day I would have to use something like you suggested.

Comment: I will discourage to use an extra library for just a simple function that can be achieved otherwise easily.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I proposed in comments.

```
var curr_time = 583027200000;
for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
    var date = new Date(curr_time);

    alert("Current: "+date.toDateString());

    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);

    alert("New: "+date.toDateString());
    curr_time = date.getTime();
}
```

Check out this fiddle.
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92e8m/)**